# Iteration over `Mongoid::Criteria` is performed less times than expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have the next sentences:

```
users = Users.where(:created_at.gte => Date.parse('2021-1-1')).order(created_at: :desc)
=>
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"created_at"=>{"$gte"=>2021-01-01 05:00:00 UTC}}
  options:  {:sort=>{"created_at"=>-1}}
  class:    User
  embedded: false>

users.count
=> 15100
```

but when `users` is iterated (`each`) and logged as following, it looks like iterate only over the last month elements:

```
users.each do |user|
  UserMailer.confirmation_email(user).deliver_now!
  File.write("log.csv", "#{user.email}, #{user.created_at}, true\n", mode: "a")
rescue
  File.write("log.csv", "#{user.email}, #{user.created_at}, false\n", mode: "a")
end
```

because `log.csv` ended up with only the records created in the last month, not from January 1th which is equivalent to 8323 records (and lines into the csv file).

Comment: Identify the last returned user and the first missing user, add them to the question.

Comment: _"when users is iterated (each) and logged as following"_ – is the problem related to that logging?